# Convert strings into float value while working on csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, type-conversion, valueerror

I got CSV files to train but while training error  is coming.

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CBH'

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - share your code

Comment: Column B contains words like `CBH`, which is not a number. You need to convert only columns I and J.

Comment: so in order to train the above data set what should i do?

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously You try to convert values of row "B" to float. And the Value "CBH" can not be converted to a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

Label Encoding can turn the available values into their own unique value.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

df = pd.read_csv('file-path')

le = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoding()
le.fit(df['code'])
df = df[le.transform(df['code'])]

# change back
df = df[le.inverse_transform(df['code'])]
```

> [Sklearn Label Encoding Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)